# Handle android:onClick event in fragment,not in fragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-fragmentactivity, listviewitem

I have a listview in Fragment.

In my listitem layout contains three buttons,like:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/msg_item_h">

<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:onClikc="onDeleteClick"
    android:text="delete" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:onClikc="onAddClick"
    android:text="add" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/msg_delete_btn_w"
    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
    android:onClikc="onEditClick"
    android:text="edit" />
```

I want to handle the event onDeleteClick,onEditClick and onAddClick in my fragment.
But everytime the fragmentActivity got the event.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: could you please show your fragments code?

Comment: when you use `onClick` in layout, then click event looks for the hooked method in current context class i.e. in `Activity` class

Comment: yes it happens because fragment itself a part of Activity(portion of activity's layout).so batter to use `setOnClickListener` with fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your fragment:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                //Do your stuff here
            }
        });
```

If you do this you wouldn't need `android:onClick="onDeleteClick"` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution handles onClick events, and works for Activity as well as Fragments:

```
public class YourFragmentClass extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml_file, container, false);

    Button delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnDelete:
            // Do something here...
           break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:onClick` delivers the event to the Context, so this is impossible.

According to View documentation:

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).